# Why isn't my combination of RUNASINVOKER and silent execution working together?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I run my `.exe` file I get prompted by the UAC to put in the admin password and after I input the password I get prompted by the `.exe` to make a `yes` or `no` selection to allow for an update.
I'm trying to run the `.exe` file silently and bypassing the UAC.

I ran two parts of the code. The first part of the code I tested runs the `.exe` file bypassing the UAC.

The second part I tested that it can run the `.exe` file silently with the exception of the UAC

both instances work, but when I put it together it does not work.

```
Set ApplicationPath="C:\Users\Field User\Desktop\20190621-001-v5i64.exe"
cmd /min /C "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start /WAIT "" %ApplicationPath%" /q
```

I expect to run the `.exe` file without the UAC and prompts

Comment: Unless we know the exact executable name and it's developer details we cannot tell you if it has options for running it from the command line without the update prompt. Batch files do not interact with a GUI, so you'd need to look into a programming language which does GUI interaction.

Comment: Have you considered splitting the second line into two separate lines and not using `cmd /min` at all?

Comment: I also tried to run as:                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                         set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER
                                                                                                                   START /WAIT "" "C:\Users\Field User\Desktop\SymantecIntelligentUpdater.exe" /q

Comment: Just and FYI if i run the command: set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER START /WAIT "" "C:\Users\Field User\Desktop\SymantecIntelligentUpdater.exe" than I bypass the UAC  but get the prompt from the executable                                                                                                            If I run the command: START /WAIT "" "C:\Users\Field User\Desktop\SymantecIntelligentUpdater.exe" /q I have to enter the admin password but I bypass the prompt from the executable  So logically I m thinking if both work than It should work together but it does not